# Extend/mixin native classes with babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs

A year ago babel [removed](https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/3878bd812c73bdd18b1011be59515dad985940fd) the ability to extend native classes. I know that extending native objects isn't always smooth, there are quirks to watch out for, but in a library I'm converting to ES2015 I only need the basics (`length`, `push`, `splice`, etc) and would rather not reinvent the wheel.

The library currently does it like this, which works in web browsers today:

```
function CustomArray() {}
CustomArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
CustomArray.prototype.constructor = CustomArray;
```

In TypeScript 1.8, I can use:

```
class CustomArray extends Array {}
```

Yet when trying the same in babel, it won't work.

I had hoped I could combine the two (which does work on its own) but due to babel/webpack packing it breaks.

```
class CustomArray {}
CustomArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
CustomArray.prototype.constructor = CustomArray;

export default CustomArray;
```

When the module is downconverted it's scoped in a way that my custom prototype solution no longer works.

My question is:

- Is there any way to get this to work with babel?
- Is there any alternate Array-like library I *can* extend?

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need? There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend to support this as long as you don't need good old IE support.

Comment: IE10+ so it seems like it's worth a shot.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! I had to use `approximate: true` for things to work in phantomjs during unit tests but so far so good. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept.